# Facing problem in Twilio VoIP in flutter - ios

Tags: ios, flutter, twilio

I'm setting accessToken and deviceToken correctly but whenever I place a call it's getting disconnected as soon as I make the request to connect.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you have built? What does your TwiML application do? Do you have an application that is correctly responding to the required webhook? Are there any errors anywhere? Either in your Flutter app, in your application that will respond to webhooks or in the Twilio console?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.